# Как правильно использовать cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport?

Tags: angular

В шаблоне есть:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50">       
 <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items">
   {{ item }}
 </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

**В app.module:**
ScrollingModule

Ошибка в шаблоне:

```
'cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport' is not a known element:
1. If 'cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Comment: Попробуйте импортировать ScrollingModule

Comment: Куда?  Уже испортировал ведь: В app.module: ScrollingModule

Comment: откуда импорт? лучше код покажите

Comment: Все отработало - кроме модуля нужно было зарегистровать сервис: ScrollDispatcher